# How do I center align form

Tags: html, css

How can I center align this form? I've tried, margin-left:auto;, margin:50px;, margin: 0 auto 0 auto; and several other codes but nothing seems to work. I want it so that everything is center aligned and if I want to add additional items they will also be centered.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ffKKN/1/

Here's the css:

```
.radio div[type='radio'] {
background: transparent;


border:0px solid #dcdcdc;
border-radius:10px;
padding:0px;
float:left;
margin-left: 10px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.radio div.active {
box-shadow:0 0 2px 0px transparent inset;
}
.tablebuttons img {
width: 60px;
height: 55px;
border: 0px solid #666;
background: #fff;
display:block;
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
}
.question {
margin-left: auto;
display: none;
clear: both;
}
.question:nth-child(1) {
display:block;
}

#linkDiv {
margin: 0;
}
.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: The width of the form is currently `auto` so it's expanding to fill it's container - which is the `<body>` - you'll need to give it a fixed width to center it using `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that forms have `block` display, and spread to 100% width of their container. You can switch the display to `inline-block` and so it'll spread according the form's children.

No fixed width required.

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
#quiz {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/ffKKN/6/)

Comment: If that's the problem, why do you need text-align center on the body? That's what's centering it, isn't it?

Comment: @JuanMendes Try and set the body's align to `center` without inline block and see what happens. (It won't work correctly)

Comment: @JoshC Thank you but you're exaggerating! :) I'm willing to admit CSS is my passion :)

Comment: @Itay It works but then again it doesn't. When I click the button and the next form pops up it goes back to the left and is not centered anymore.

Comment: @user2680614 You didn't mention anything about another form. Does your other form have the same ID (`#quiz`)?

Comment: Your problem is that `.radio div[type="radio"]` have a floating setting. Remove `float:left` and replace it with `display: inline-block;`

Comment: @Itay works fine now but is there any way to have my text in the 3 form to be aligned left but the form still be centered?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36958/discussion-between-itay-and-user2680614)

Comment: If you don't want your text to be center aligned, use `#quiz {text-align: left}`

Answer (score 3):

Set a width, then use `margin:0px auto;`

```
#quiz {
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Additionally, if you want the text to be center *within* the container, use

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/uv7fJ/)

Comment: body width? I don't get it. Also shouldn't the width of the form be fluid?

Comment: @JuanMendes the OP asked a question, I gave an answer. Of course you could make it fluid, if you feel this is important, make an answer taking that approach.

Comment: Just because I mention a drawback in your approach, it doesn't mean that I'm going to take the time or even know of a better one. I'm just making sure it's clear that this technique works for elements with fixed width only.

Answer (score 1):

In your css add this line :

```
#quiz { margin:0 auto; width:350px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `<div class="iphone3gscarrier">` that you are using in place of radio buttons to a `<span>` tag instead, and use the following css:

```
body {
text-align: center;
}
```

They are now centered. You may add as many  tags as you like, and everything will stay centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZBMgZ/

Comment: What's the difference with the span and the div?

Comment: @user2680614 `span` is inline, it could have been done by doing `.iphone{display: inline}`

Answer (score 1):

If you can use flexbox layout, this is the only way to center elements without resorting to tables, text-align, or fixed widths.

http://jsfiddle.net/tuu4y/

#### HTML

```
<form>
    <label>Hello <input /> </label>    
</form>
```

#### CSS

```
form {
    display: inline block;
   /* flexbox, por favor */
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
   -webkit-box-pack: center;
   -webkit-box-align: center;

  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;

  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  box-pack: center;
  box-align: center;    
}
```

If you have to support older browsers, and you can hardcode the width http://jsfiddle.net/tuu4y/4/

```
form {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 5px auto;   
}
```

If you can't hardcode the width, you could use any of the three tricks, some don't validate, and some are shunned upon. They all require making the form `inline-block`

#### Use text-align: center in the wrapping container

If you don't want the text to be center aligned, you have to put `text-align:left` on the form itself http://jsfiddle.net/tuu4y/2/

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
form {
    display: inline-block;   
    text-align: left;
}
```

#### Put a wrapper `<form align="center">...</form>`,

Doesn't validate though http://jsfiddle.net/tuu4y/1/

```
<form align="center">
    <label>Hello <input /> </label>    
</form>
```